# iterating over numpy array using lambda

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, lambda

I have a numpy array of numbers like this:`cols = np.arange(1, 6)`. I want to append the letter 't' in front of every number in cols. I write the followind loc:

```
f = lambda x: 't' + str(x)
temp = f(cols)
print(temp)
```

I get an output like this:

```
t[1 2 3 4 5].
```

I need the output to be ['t1', 't2', 't3'...]. I need to do it for 1000s of numbers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The idea of lambda is that it is anonymous so you don't need to assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `np.core.char.add`:

```
np.core.char.add('t', np.arange(1,6).astype(str))
#array(['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5'], 
#      dtype='|S12')
```

---

It's faster then `list(map(...))` for large arrays:

```
%timeit np.core.char.add('t', np.arange(1,100000).astype(str))
# 10 loops, best of 3: 31.7 ms per loop

f = lambda x: 't' + str(x)
%timeit list(map(f, np.arange(1,100000).astype(str)))
# 10 loops, best of 3: 38.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: The speed difference is even larger in my computer: `82.6ms` for `np.core.char.add` while `163ms` for `list(map(...))`.

Answer (score 4):

You can to do that with list comprehension:

```
['t' + str(x) for x in cols]
['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6']
```

This will append 't' for every element `x` in collection cols.

`lambda` function is an anonymous function, so you usually pass it into functions that expects a callable object.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your applying your function to the *entire* array. Your basically doing:

```
't' + str(cols)
```

Which of course does not work. You need to apply it *element*-wise:

```
list(map(f, cols)) # No need for list() if using Python 2
```